# Running App for Android

Tags: android, sport

So I want an app

- for Android
- where you can create your own route for running (by drawing it on a map)
- When you are running the app tells you where to turn (like a car navigation).

Also the app needs to have an option to hear to voice in something else than English, (English is not my first language).

Does this app exist, so yes, where can I find it?

Comment: How do you want to create that route? a) by walking it, b) importing GPX tracks, c) drawing it on a map… Some running apps you can find [in my app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sport_fitness#group_1084), but they are mostly for tracking. [OsmAnd](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.osmand.plus/) could cover the navigation part, and can import GPX tracks (you can also find it in the toy shop… ahem, play store if you insist).

Comment: @Izzy sorry for reaction so late, but I have go with c drawing it on a map

Comment: Ah, in that case I must pass. Would it be acceptable to prepare the route with a different app (or on a website, or in some other drawing-way on a PC)? And could you also reveal *what* other language(s) voice navigation must be available in? I somehow doubt English is the only language which isn't your first :)

Comment: @Izzy don't worry about is I think OsmAnd is pretty good I have been using it for two days now. it supports the language that is my main and the app even says when I need to turn and where. I don't even mind that you can't fully customise your route. for me the problem has been solved. it was soo good that even my mom wanted to try it. :)

Comment: Glad to read! So shall I put OsmAnd as answer? I just discovered a manual for it (which I funnily bookmarked years ago but only know got to read, luckily it was updated just a few days ago), which covers track creation and more. It's in German, though. And author creates tracks on PC…

Comment: @Izzy ofcouse you can put it as an anwser I will even accept it. oh if you do that can you also give me the link to the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not specifically a „running app“, **[OsmAnd](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.osmand.plus/)** seems to mostly fit your needs:

- **for Android:** Yes (there's also an iOS version I've heard)
- **where you can create your own route for running (by drawing it on a map):** I've not discovered that yet: it allows for route planning (including [trip planning](https://osmand.net/features/trip-planning)), and routes can be exported as GPX tracks. Alternatively, there's some online and PC software to "draw routes" manually and export them as GPX, which then can be imported to OsmAnd.
- **When you are running the app tells you where to turn (like a car navigation):** Yes. OsmAnd uses a TTS engine for that.
- **voice in something else than English:** Yes to that as well. Though I have no list of supported languages.

OsmAnd is also available [at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus) if you insist, and you can find additional details including screenshots [at its website](https://osmand.net/). It's a full-fledged navigation app for drivers, cyclists and pedestrians alike, open source, and based on Open Streetmap (the name stands for „Open Street Map Automated Navigation Directions” if you wonder. If you got an OSM account, you can even use it to contribute to Open Street Map. It's an excellent and reliable piece of software which I can warmly recommend, using it myself.